# How can use a centrality metrics in Gremlin on the text file?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Please someone send me the correct code in (apache-tinkerpop(Gremlin) for both(closeness centrality, betweenness centrality, PageRank, and EiegenValue ) metrics without any error during the execution step on the list file dataset that like ("edges.txt) file.

**Note: This is a sample of the ("edges.txt") datasets that include only the source and destination vertex without any properties(only two columns)** as shown below:

*Source Destination*

1 2

2  3

2  4

3  5

4  5

5  6

Comment: I provided an answer with a link below, but please note that questions often get closed by moderators when they lack a significant degree of specificity. In general it's recommended to show what you have tried so far and not ask others to provide code. Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a good guide on how to write a question.

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start is the Gremlin Recipes document which can be found [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/). Doing these types of calculation all in Gremlin will work at modest scale but for a large graph you may need to consider other approaches.